# Chrome Cache is driving me CRAZY

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, caching

I have the cache turned off in chrome but whenever I reload the page to review my jquery and css changes it doesn't hard refresh from the server.

I have to sit there and hard refresh manually millions of times to get my changes in the dom.

Sometimes when I am troubleshooting I am trying out various changes and this caching thing is driving me nuts. If I have the cache turned off, why is it not always refreshing from server????

Comment: Millions of times? Wow, you're more patient than I would be.

Comment: Ctrl+F5 is your friend.

Comment: Do you refresh with F5 or control + F5?

Comment: Just to be sure . . . did you try a manual hard refresh? Or just a normal reload?

Comment: If you can't resolve this, one thing you can do in Chrome - with the developer tools window open, you can right-click on the refresh button and there's the option for "Empty Cache and Hard Reload"

Comment: Does `chrome://cache/` shows any entries? If there is anything listed, then cache has not cleared. Also, open try opening DevTools then *Right click* on the reload button and choose _Empty Cache and Hard Reload_ to really, _really_ clear it all.

Comment: Where have you turned off cache, in the F12 developer tools? If so this only disables cache when developer tools is opened

Comment: I've tuned it off in the tools with the dev tool open,Ive also tried the reload button via right click. YEah I always use cntrl+f5. One thing I am seeing in google is that it might be some kind of eclipse/apache bug. Something to do with timestamps or something

Answer (score 0):

try `crl+r` to refresh the page it will clear your browser, hope it will works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the browser cache via the command line using the steps below:

Find the Chrome program icon.

Right click it and choose Properties.

In the Target box, add --disk-cache-size=1 --media-cache-size=1 at the end of chrome.exe.

Clear your cache and you should be good to go, cache free.

This ensures the cache doesn't have the size to grow. Turning off the cache using developer tools only works when developer tools are open.

Hope this helps